# Taking limit of a sequence inside discrete distribution function

Tags: limits, binomial-distribution

Suppose that there exists a positive, integer sequence $\{c_k\}$, satisfying $c_k\geq c^*$, such that $c_k\to c^*$. Further suppose that $X$ is a binomial random variable with size $n$ and parameter $p$.
Now,
$$
P(X>c_k)=P(X>c^*)-P(c^*<X\leq c_k)
$$
I'm interested in the limit
$$
\lim_{c_k\downarrow c^*}P(c^*<X\leq c_k)
$$
Does this limit exist?

**Context**

I'm trying to show that $P(X>c_k)\to P(X>c^*)$, but since $X$, and hence $P(X>x)$ is discrete, I don't think that the limit can pass inside so nicely. Rather I think the difference between $P(X>c_k)$ and $P(X>c^*)$ should involve some local limit (i.e. a gap jump) like $P(X=c^*)$. However, I'm not sure if I'm overthinking it or can show that this local limit is indeed present.

Comment: $c_k \le c^*$ or $c_k \ge c^*$?

Comment: In the first line, $c_k \le c^*$, in the fifth line $c^* < X \le c_k$ and $c_k \downarrow c^*$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. I've edited the question to be clearer. I'm interested in the case $c_k\geq c^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $c_k$ is a sequence of positive integers, hence for there exists $N$ such that $k > N \implies c_k=c^*$.

Hence for $k>N$, $Pr(c^* < X \le c_k)=Pr(c^* < X \le c^*)=0$.

We have $$\lim \limits_{c_k \downarrow c^*}Pr(c^* < X \le c_k)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For any random variable $X$ we have $P\{X=c^{*}\}=\lim P\{c_k<X\leq c^{*}\}$ if $c_k \leq c^{*}$ and $c_k \to c^{*}$. (This follows from the fact that $\{c^{*}\}=\cap_k (c_k,c^{*}]$ and continuity property of the measure induced by $X$).

Comment: Thank you. I made a typo in my original statement of the question. It should have been $c_k\geq c^*$. I am, however, aware of the result you gave, as it was included in my original statement.